# Facebook Graph API `/me/accounts` returns empty list if the account itself is a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a website where users can manage their restaurants. They can connect each restaurant to the corresponding fb page, if any.

This works perfectly well if the user has a normal Facebook account and is administrator of these pages. I ask for `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` and after the user gave access to our service, I present them a list of pages to choose from using the `/me/accounts` endpoint.

**But**, now one of our users doesn't have a private Facebook account. He signed up on Facebook *as a page*, with no personal information. The `/me/accounts` call returns an empty list. And afaik Facebook doesn't allow developers to create these kind of test users (only normal, private fb accounts), which makes it impossible to debug.

So did anyone of you already come across this and know how to solve it?